# How to access transaction data from Tally ODBC database

Tags: sql, database, odbc

I am trying to access tally database through ODBC connection(Tally.ERP 9).
I able to access most of the tables through TallyODBC_9000 connection.
But i am **unable to access** neither **transaction data** nor **system tables** present in the tally database.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The following method works fine for me; I got all my data back from database.

Connect your tally database to SQL Server 2010. After successful connection, install Visual Studio 2013.

Using Visual Studio 2013, select connect to database. Select tables you want to open, right click and select retrieve data from table. You will get all the data from database file.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and now 2016  ......